# Writing Sql Update method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, methods

```
public static int SQLUpdate(string sql, string[] names, object[] values)
{
        if (names.Length != values.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("name/value mismatch");
        }

        using (var sqlconn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString))
        {
            sqlconn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlconn))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(names[i], values[i]);
                }

                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I wrote method to create `Update` command.

For example I have a `Picture` table in my SQL Server database with `PictureID, UserID` columns.

And user can add 3 pictures at once. You see `values` is `array`.

But in my example `value[i]` also is `array`. (3 pictures).

How can I write my `SQLUpdate` `method` for this ?

Comment: Why not to excecute command for each `(names[i];values[i,j])`

Comment: @MikkaRin OP says values[i] is an array

Comment: @Bharadwaj OP is user3461906. Not me.

Comment: @Bharadwaj , my code save data, no proplem, just I need to improve it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there except I would switch your code around a little so:

```
sqlconn.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
     {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlconn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(names[i], values[i]);

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
```

**AS you are declaring a new SQLCommand everytime you may need to do cmd.Close() and cmd.Dispose() each time.

Comment: As I declared everything works normal.
I need method that values[i] is also array.

Comment: From the code you have given us values[] is an array and assuming that your names and values are input in a relational order then i will do fine as names[0] will relate to value[0].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass data table in SQL procedure

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S
```

Comment: I dont know stored procedure. I want to write C# method

Comment: Can u check this link  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S